# c++ Errors with Class Codes

Tags: c++

I keep getting various errors in my code can someone please run it through their compiler and help me resolve them?? I fixed a few and the one I am getting now is no matching function for call to 'classRooms::ClassRooms(std::string&, int&, .....

//classRoom.h

```
#ifndef CLASSROOMS_H
#define CLASSROOMS_H

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "ClassRooms.h"

using namespace std;

class ClassRooms
{
public:

    ClassRooms(int nRooms=100)
        : numRooms(0), rooms(new ClassRooms[nRooms]) { }
    ~ClassRooms()
    {
        delete [] rooms;
    }
    void addRoom(const ClassRooms& cr)
    {
        rooms[numRooms++] = cr;
    }
    string findRoom(int seats)const;
    int getSeats();
    double getAreaPerSeat();
   string getRoomNumber();
private:
    int numRooms;
    ClassRooms *rooms;
    int numSeats;
    double length, width;

};

#endif //CLASSROOMS_H
```

//ClassRooms.h

```
#ifndef CLASSROOMS_H
#define CLASSROOMS_H

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "classRoom.h"

using namespace std;

class ClassRooms
{
public:
    ClassRooms(int nRooms=100)
        : numRooms(0), rooms(new ClassRooms[nRooms]) { }
    ~ClassRooms()
    {
        delete [] rooms;
    }
   void addRoom(const ClassRooms& cr)
    {
        rooms[numRooms++] = cr;
    }
    string findRoom(int seats)const;
private:
    int numRooms;
    ClassRooms *rooms;
};

#endif //CLASSROOMS_H
```

//main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include "ClassRooms.h"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    ifstream fin("rooms.txt");
    if (!fin)
    {
        cout << "Cannot open file\n";
        return 1;
    }
    string roomNum;
    int seats;
    double len, wid;
    ClassRooms classRooms;

    while (fin >> roomNum >> seats >> len >> wid)
        classRooms.addRoom(ClassRooms(roomNum, seats, len, wid));
    fin.close();

    while (seats > 0)
    {
        cout << "Enter MAX capacity: ";
        cin >> seats;
        cout << "Your best room is " << classRooms.findRoom(seats) << endl;
    }
}
```

//ClassRooms.cpp

```
#include "classRoom.h"

string ClassRooms::findRoom(int seats)const
{
    int maxIndex = 0;
    while (maxIndex < numRooms && rooms[maxIndex].getSeats() < seats)
        ++maxIndex;
    if (maxIndex == numRooms) return "";

    for (int i = 0; i < numRooms; ++i)
        if (rooms[i].getSeats() >= seats
                && rooms[i].getAreaPerSeat() > rooms[maxIndex].getAreaPerSeat())
            maxIndex = i;
    return rooms[maxIndex].getRoomNumber();
}
```

Comment: `classRoom.h`, `ClassRooms.h`, `class ClassRooms`, `class ClassRooms`. I'm confused.

Comment: Both classRoom.h and classRooms.h defines class ClassRooms, you should start there.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Your question doesn't clearly explain what problems you are encountering - you should try to include the actual compiler errors you are receiving. When seeking help with an issue like this you should try to show what errors you are encountering and attempt to demonstrate what actions you have taken to resolve them yourself. Please see the [How to ask questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) FAQ for advice on how to ask questions. The folks here answering questions are here to try and help, not do your work for you.

Answer (score 0):

You have no `Classrooms` constructor that takes a `(string, int, double, double)`, so therefore, this `ClassRooms(roomNum, seats, len, wid)` is an error. You can easily add an appropriate constructor to `Classrooms` though.

```
ClassRooms(string roomNum, int seats, double len, double wid){
    //do something
}
```